# Firebase real time database (not uploading)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm facing an issue when trying to upload to firebase, I have instantiated every variable so I think that's not the problem I'm getting the error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
Exactly on this line String milkQuantity = milkq.getText().toString(); this is located in:

```
    private void createPopupDialog(){
    dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup2, null);

    dialogBuilder.setView(view);
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            //start posting
            String milkQuantity = milkq.getText().toString();
            String note = noteText.getText().toString();

            if(!milkQuantity.equals("") && !noteText.equals("")){
                BlogCalendar detailsInfo = new BlogCalendar(milkQuantity, note);
                m
```

DatabaseReference.child("MmilkDetails").child(userId).setValue(detailsInfo);
}else{

```
            }


        }
    });
```

and in my .xml file the edit texts are:

```
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/milkQuantity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:hint="@string/milkQty"
            android:textColorHint="#5E5E5E" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/noteText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/milkQuantity"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
            android:hint="@string/notes_hint"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:textColorHint="#5E5E5E" />
```

in case you wonder yeah the variables are instantiated

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar_);



    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDatabaseReference = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MmilkDetails");
    userId = mUser.getUid();



    blogCalendarList = new ArrayList<>();

    recyclerView2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCalendarActivity);
    recyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mDatabaseReference.keepSynced(true);

    milkq =  findViewById(R.id.milkQuantity);
    noteText =  findViewById(R.id.noteText);
```

Comment: milkq is null at the time you're trying to use it.

Comment: what is the name of the xml file that has milkQuantity and noteText?, it just says .xml.

Comment: @HaroldSer the nameof the file is popup.xml

Comment: @JoséAndrésMolinaGarcia I have responded why in detail, the reason of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the NullPointerException is because milkQuantity is defined in popup.xml and you are doing findViewById from R.layout.activity_calendar_ (Inside onCreate() method)

```
milkq =  findViewById(R.id.milkQuantity);//this will assign null to milkq, hence the 
                                         //nullpointer exception later.
```

You either need to have the milkQuantity in R.layout.activity_calendar_ or do below code in your onCreate() method:

```
setContentView(R.layout.popup.xml); //instead of setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendar_);
```

Happy Coding!